# CAShapeLayer with CAReplicatorLayer performance optimization

Tags: ios, performance, core-graphics, core-animation

I'm using a CAShapeLayer as the subview of a CAReplicatorLayer.

It's drawing 12 instances that are just slightly moved away from each other (for performance testing).

On touch move, I'm seting a new path on the CAShapeLayer that is slightly different to the previous one, so that it looks like an animation depending on the user input / touch direction.

Unfortunately the frame rate goes down to under 30 fps when doing this as soon as the shape gets about half the size of the iPad screen (iPad 3).

I tried to rasterize the CAShapeLayer which greatly improves the performance but only as long as the CAShapeLayer is rather small. Rasterizing the CAReplicatorLayer doesn't help either.

I would also be happy to just turn off the fill of the shapeLayers during user input but I couldn't find a way yet to have it work. Setting the transparency of the fill to 0 is not helpful at all, performance-wise.

But that would just be the "last hope". What can I do to boost the performance in general?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CoreAnimation performance profiling - CAReplicatorLayer with CAShapeLayer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156543/coreanimation-performance-profiling-careplicatorlayer-with-cashapelayer)